# MySQL dando erro apenas quando uso a query via variável

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando salvar uma informação no meu banco de dados com as seguintes funções:

```
$sql = $request[0];
$query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

var_dump do $sql:

```
string(322) "INSERT INTO Fornecedor (razao_social, nome_fantasia, telefone, 
 email, tipo_fornecedor, logadouro, numero, bairro, cep, cidade, estado, 
 pais) VALUES ('teste', 'outra coisa', '345923942394', 
  'mighuel@mighuel.com', '0', 'rua aldm', '211', 'sdfsdfsdfsdf', '188-5852', 
  'marilia', 'sum paulo', 'brazil');"
```

Porém, ao ser executado o código me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1"

E eu não tenho idéia do que pode estar acontecendo, pois se eu colocar o valor de $sql dentro da função prepare, assim:

```
$query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Fornecedor (razao_social, 
 nome_fantasia, telefone, email, tipo_fornecedor, logadouro, numero, bairro, 
 cep, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES ('teste', 'outra coisa', '345923942394', 
 'mighuel@mighuel.com', '0', 'rua aldm', '211', 'sdfsdfsdfsdf', '188-5852', 
 'marilia', 'sum paulo', 'brazil');");
```

Ele salva a informação normalmente.

retorno bin2hex($sql):
`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`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedi um HexDump para entender a razão do seu Dump original indicar 322 caracteres numa string de cerca de 300.

Justamente, no seu HexDump, noto que tem várias sequências do caractere `Nul` (`00`), o que é inválido numa *query*.

Isto é um problema no envio da informação, ou em algum processamento anterior da string, e não do código que se encontra na pergunta.

Uma vez arrumado o envio e recebimento, os resultados devem voltar à normalidade. Resista à tentação de tratar o valor, pois criará outros problemas. Melhor consertar o erro original.

Marquei com `*` os `Nul`, para facilitar a visualização:

```
49 4e 53 45 52 54 20 49 4e 54 4f 20 46 6f 72 6e 65 63 65 64 6f 72 20 28*00*00 72 61
7a 61 6f 5f 73 6f 63 69 61 6c 2c 20*00*00 6e 6f 6d 65 5f 66 61 6e 74 61 73 69 61 2c
20*00*00 74 65 6c 65 66 6f 6e 65 2c 20*00*00 65 6d 61 69 6c 2c 20*00*00 74 69 70 6f
5f 66 6f 72 6e 65 63 65 64 6f 72 2c 20*00*00 6c 6f 67 61 64 6f 75 72 6f 2c 20*00*00
6e 75 6d 65 72 6f 2c 20*00*00 62 61 69 72 72 6f 2c 20*00*00 63 65 70 2c 20*00*00 63
69 64 61 64 65 2c 20*00*00 65 73 74 61 64 6f 2c 20*00*00 70 61 69 73 29 20 56 41 4c
55 45 53 20 28 27 74 65 73 74 65 27 2c 20 27 6f 75 74 72 61 20 63 6f 69 73 61 27 2c
20 27 33 34 35 39 32 33 39 34 32 33 39 34 27 2c 20 27 6d 69 67 68 75 65 6c 40 6d 69
67 68 75 65 6c 2e 63 6f 6d 27 2c 20 27 30 27 2c 20 27 72 75 61 20 61 6c 64 6d 27 2c
20 27 32 31 31 27 2c 20 27 73 64 66 73 64 66 73 64 66 73 64 66 27 2c 20 27 31 38 38
2d 35 38 35 32 27 2c 20 27 6d 61 72 69 6c 69 61 27 2c 20 27 73 75 6d 20 70 61 75 6c
6f 27 2c 20 27 62 72 61 7a 69 6c 27 29 3b
```